# Is it permissible to make wudu in the kitchen sink

Tags: wudu

In the apartment I live  there is no wudu station.  Is it permissible to make wudu after stepping out the toilet and make wudu in the kitchen sink?

Comment: Do we need wudu' station - Whatever that may be- to perform wudu'?

Comment: Medi1Saif♦ There is no need of wudu' station. It is enough where there is a tap and the place is clean and free from _najis_.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for the location where you do wudu nor the apparatus that you use. You can do it in your washroom, kitchen, outside or even in your lounge. You can use a tap / sink or a bowl or waterskin or river etc.